# How can I figure out which architecture I'm compiling for in GCC?

Tags: architecture, assembly, cross-platform

I want to write code that compiles easily for either 32 or 64 bit linux under gcc.  I guess I'm looking for something like

```
#ifdef IA32
subl $0x4, %esp
#endif

#ifdef X86_64
subl $0x4, %rsp
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what you're looking for is [_LP64](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros), which is defined when pointer size is 64-bit wide

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following should work:

```
#if defined __i386__
subl $0x4, %esp
#elif defined __x86_64__
subq $0x4, %rsp
#else
#error Unknown architecture!
#endif
```

Fixed the suffix on `sub` in the 64-bit code for you, too =)